# flink checkpoint and kafka producer exactly-once

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I create kafka producer with exactly once, if I also use checkpoint, it will lead to such problem:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1260)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1155)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1132)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close(KafkaProducer.java:1111)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.FlinkKafkaInternalProducer.close(FlinkKafkaInternalProducer.java:150)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.abortTransactions(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:1093)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.initializeState(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:1031)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:281)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:881)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:395)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It is unclear how exactly you run into this problem. See also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to put an appropriate [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) into the question.

Comment: What @colidyre said: Please provide also which version of flink and kafka you are using

Comment: The version of flink is 1.9.1. And I just run code like this:                                               
`env.enableCheckpointing(60000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
env.addSource(...).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(topic, kafkaSerializationSchema(topic, serializer),properties,FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE));`

Comment: What's the source? E.g. if it's bounded, then your workflow would terminate quickly, before any checkpointing happens.

Comment: It is also kafka source.